# (MySQL) How do I add an item id to all users?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new on programming, sorry if I can't explain my doubt very well...

My friend have a online game and I help him to manage it. The php has a table for the users (`meh_users`), and a table for the items that the users have (`meh_users_items`). Each item has a id, (column `itemid`) and also the users (column `userid`), and in the table of the items that the users have, there is a id for the combination of the user and the item. (just `id`, and sorry, I don't understand this so much).

There is an image, if this make more easy to understand me:

[phpMyAdmin printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LyYI.jpg)

I want to add an item (let's think that it's a sword and this item have the id 3454) to all the users, but I don't want to delete the other items that the users have. Also I don't want to insert the data on the table one by one, because it's more than a hundred users.

Hope I have said enough details!

Remember: I'm new and I already search soooo much in the internet before asking here.

Comment: On which table do you want to update, `meh_users` or `meh_users_teims`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you want to give that sword to all users, including ones that already have it. You don't need PHP for this, SQL is enought.

`INSERT INTO meh_users_items (userid, itemid, equipped)
SELECT userid, 3454, 0
FROM meh_users`

This is just an example. You need to add all field to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Three steps:

1. If it isn't there already, add the new item (e.g., the Sword of Power) to your meh_items table.
2. Get a list of all your users from the meh_user table.
3. Write a foreach statement creating an entry in the meh_users_items table for each user.

It also occurs to me that your database might have some setup issues. E.g., meh_users_items has a column indicating item type (e.g., weapon). That could end up being problematic. Better to keep that information with the items in the meh_items table.